# Circular path for sprite?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to build a game using xcode 6.1 and swift and one of the key elements is having a ball go around in circles (not rotating around own axis but following circular path). How can I accomplish this the most efficiently? Here is the code I tried.

```
func rotate(){

    newBall = balls(size: self.size, positionX: -36, positionY: 250)
    var path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, 0)
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 15, 15, CGFloat(M_PI_2), CGFloat(M_PI_2), true)
    newBall.node.path = path
    self.addChild(newBall.node)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    rotate()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember that creating apparently zero-length paths doesn't always have the expected results.  Try splitting the path up:

```
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 15, 15, CGFloat(M_PI_2), -CGFloat(M_PI_2), true)
CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 0, 15, 15, -CGFloat(M_PI_2), CGFloat(M_PI_2), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a ton of ways to do this.  I'll just show you one way

you can copy paste this code and modify to your needs

```
// add sprite to scene
let mysprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
mysprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
self.addChild(mysprite)

// the circle path's diameter
let circleDiameter = CGFloat(100)

// center our path based on our sprites initial position
let pathCenterPoint = CGPoint(
    x: mysprite.position.x - circleDiameter/2,
    y: mysprite.position.y - circleDiameter/2
)

// create the path our sprite will travel along
let circlePath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: pathCenterPoint, size: CGSize(width: circleDiameter, height: circleDiameter)), nil)

// create a followPath action for our sprite
let followCirclePath = SKAction.followPath(circlePath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, duration: 2)

// make our sprite run this action forever
mysprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(followCirclePath))
```

Comment: `CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect` is only available on OS X.

Comment: @David I just ran this on my iphone no problem.  have you tried it?  I'm on the latest xcode

Comment: Hmm... checked the reference because I thought I remembered this being OS X-only it wasn't in the reference, but it's apparently been supported since iOS 5.0.

Comment: thank you. just a question, what is .runAction(), because i dont have have that as a member of GameScene.balls, which is my sprite class. is there a more general way to put it?

Comment: you should be able to use runAction on any class that inherits from SKNode

Comment: oh its because i dont have it as an skspritenode